# Windows Azure Active Directory Authentication Exception

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, x509certificate, azure-active-directory

I'm using Windows Azure Active Directory Authentication. This is used to secure a c# windows service that calls a c# Web API service in Azure.It has worked for quite some time but now I've started getting the following exception:

```
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware Error: 0 : Authentication failed
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve SecurityKeyIdentifier: 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
(
    IsReadOnly = False,
    Count = 2,
    Clause[0] = X509ThumbprintKeyIdentifierClause(Hash = 0x61B44041161C13F9A8B56549287AF02C16DDFFDB),
    Clause[1] = System.IdentityModel.Tokens.NamedKeySecurityKeyIdentifierClause
)
```

I have no idea what this means or how to fix it :(

**Update**

In answer to the comment about key rollover my web service is using the following code:

```cs
private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
        new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
            },
            Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"]
        });
}
```

which according to that link means it should be secured against this type of issue.

The start of the token including the kid looks like this:

```
token: '{"typ":"JWT","alg":"RS256","x5t":"YbRAQRYcE_motWVJKHrwLBbd_9s","kid":"YbRAQRYcE_motWVJKHrwLBbd_9s"}
```

**Update 2**

My code to acquire token in the windows service:

```
    internal string GetAuthorizationToken()
    {
        string authority = String.Format(aadInstance, tenant);
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

        var authResult = AcquireToken(authContext);

        return authResult == null ? null : authResult.CreateAuthorizationHeader();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Acquires the token.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="authContext">The authentication context.</param>
    /// <returns>Authentication Result</returns>
    private AuthenticationResult AcquireToken(AuthenticationContext authContext)
    {
        try
        {

            return authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(apiResourceId, clientId, new UserPasswordCredential(user, pass)).Result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: could this be related to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-signing-key-rollover ?

Answer (score 0):

This exception would occur when the application trying to find the signing key via the key identity in the token from Azure, however the key on Azure already rollover.

Please get a new access token in the windows service to fix this issue.

Comment: The service though gets a new key every time it contacts the web service.

Comment: Would you mind capturing the token using **Fiddler** and decoder it via [here](https://jwt.io/)? What's the value of `kid` in the token?

Comment: Added to my original post Fei and interestingly when I use that tool you linked too it also says invalid signature.

Comment: That to me says the issue is client side in generating the token

Comment: @DasDave The key is not able to find on Azure side. We can check it from this [link](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys). Did you use the TokenCache? Would you mind sharing the piece of code about acquiring the token?

Comment: Added again to my original post and no don't use a cache. Basically the windows service only sends messages sporadically when a change is made to a system elsewhere by the user. Only one message is ever sent so didn't see the point in caching the token.

Comment: I should also say i am using login.windows.net as my AADInstance so is this the correct link https://login.windows.net/common/discovery/v2.0/keys ?

Comment: Yes, the correct links is login.windows.net/common/discovery/v2.0/keys, however the keys is same as the endpoint of login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys. Have you fixed this issue? If not, based on the code, it would using the default TokenCache. Please try to restart the windows service to clear the cache in the memory.

Comment: I'm running in debug so restarting all the time. I have several app registrations in Active directory in Azure e.g. one for test/production etc. All work apart from this test one. They return valid tokens with 'kid' values that can be found at that link. Only one app registration seems to have this problem. I could recreate it but i fear this problem could happen again in production.